# Вычисление количества месяцев между двумя датами

Tags: c#, время, datetime

Как вычислить количество месяцев между двумя датами в месяцах с округлением в большую сторону?

Т.е. период: с 15.08.2017 по 01.01.2018. Тут разница получается 4 месяца 15 дней, но надо округлять до 5 месяцев. Написал следующий код, но он верно считает только если года разные, а если взять период 01.01.2018 по 15.05.2018, то он считает как 4 месяца уже, хотя должно быть 5. Как можно еще посчитать интервал дат?

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2017,08,15);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2018,01,01);

var d3 = (d2.Month - d1.Month) + 12 * (d2.Year - d1.Year);

Console.WriteLine(d3.ToString());
```

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4638993/6766879

Comment: *он верно считает* только если номер дня начала больше номера дня окончания. Попробуйте что-нить типа `var d3 = (d2.Month - d1.Month) + 12 * (d2.Year - d1.Year) + (d2.Day < d1.Day ? 1 : 0);` (проверьте, писано на коленке - в т.ч. если дни равны).

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно чётко сформулировать что считать месяцем, например зависит ли это от месяцев входящих в диапазон и сделать набор юнит-тестов с результатами которые вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 1):

Понятие периода "месяц" довольно размытое (28 дней это месяц? 62 дня июля-августа это 2 месяца или 3? А 59 дней января-февраля это 2 или 1?), но если вам нужно примерно, то наверное и так сойдёт:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2017,08,15);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2018,01,01);
var span = d2 - d1;
var months = Math.Ceiling(span.TotalDays / 30.4);
```

Comment: @Akina а что 31 января и 1 марта?

Comment: А автору по условию *с округлением в **большую** сторону* надо в этом случае получить в ответе 2 месяца, а не 1... Согласись, что первый месяц закончится 28/29 февраля. Впрочем, ты оговорил, что "месяц" - это ОБС, потому я и коммент удалил.

Comment: @Akina совершенно верно, без строгого определения, что считать месяцем невозможно тут дать корректный ответ. Например 62 дня июля-августа это 2 месяца или 3? А 59 дней января-февраля это 2 или 1?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2017, 08, 15);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01);
int res = 0;
while (d1.AddMonths(res) < d2) ++res;
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Обратите внимание, что если d1 > d2 даты нужно поменять местами, учтите этот случай самостоятельно.

Comment: Попробуйте в вашем примере посчитать разницу между 2017-08-15 и 2017-01-01 - выдаёт ноль. Уже готовый ответ есть на en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639057/5752652

Comment: @AK, кстати в этом ответе, что вы предлагаете как раз код как у автора и он ему не подходит.

Comment: @AK, ну да, будет 0 (я по ошибке написал зациклится), просто надо даты поменять местами и взять противоположное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Кто-то должен был это сделать))

Метод расширения возвращает количество полных месяцев между заданными датами. Независимо от того, в каком порядке получены даты, всегда будет возвращено натуральное число.

```
/// <summary>
/// Возвращает разницу между датами в месяцах.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="current">Первая рассматриваемая дата.</param>
/// <param name="another">Вторая рассматриваемая дата.</param>
/// <returns>Число полных месяцев между указанными датами.</returns>
public static int DifferenceInMonths(this DateTime current, DateTime another)
{
    DateTime previous, next;
    if (current > another)
    {
        previous = another;
        next     = current;
    }
    else
    {
        previous = current;
        next     = another;
    }

    return
        (next.Year - previous .Year) * 12     // разницу в годах умножаем на 12 месяцев
      + next.Month - previous .Month          // добавляем разницу в месяцах
      // если день следующей даты не достиг дня предыдущей, 
      // то последний месяц ещё не закончился
      + (previous.Day <= next.Day ? 0 : -1); 
}
```

Но если вы всё же хотите получить дробные части месяцев, Вам просто нужно добавить еще одно слагаемое к возвращаемому значению:

`+ (next.Day - previous.Day) / DateTime.DaysInMonth(previous.Year, previous.Month)`

Оригинал этого ответа есть на [международном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73305207/7028019).