# Расчет количества лет между двумя датами введенными в textbox (дд.мм.гггг)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Имеется 2 textbox

В 1 введена дата рождения, в другой дата смерти. Как можно реализовать подсчет количества лет для ввода в 3 textbox возраста на момент смерти?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+DateTime

Comment: Также как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818508/218063 только вместо `AddMonths` использовать `AddYears`

Comment: PashaPash - обратите внимание на то, что ни один из прежних ответов не даёт правильного (100%) вычисления, с методами `.Add`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант первый:

```
public static int GetAge(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    var r = d2.Year - d1.Year;
    return d1.AddYears(r) <= d2 ? r : r -1;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ответ на комментарии PashaPash добавлю код с его, и моим методом.

```
class Program
{
    public static int GetAge1(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        return d2.Year - d1.Year - 1 +
            ((d2.Month > d1.Month || d2.Month == d1.Month && d2.Day >= d1.Day) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public static int GetAge2(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        var r = d2.Year - d1.Year;
        return d1.AddYears(r) <= d2 ? r : r -1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("01.01.1997 12:00:00");
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("01.01.2000 12:00:00");
        Console.WriteLine($"method 1: Age = {GetAge1(d1, d2)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"method 2: Age = {GetAge2(d1, d2)}");
         Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Оба эти метода уже были в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669903/177221 (имена переменных только чуть отличаются)